# NoClassDefFoundError when using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am using OpenCV and I am trying to build an Android application that does image processing. I set up OpenCV with steps [described here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html). It's working fine in Eclipse, but when I try to run it in Android, it crashes.

Here is my code

```
public class Extract {

    public Bitmap croppedImage(Bitmap b, Rect r){
        Bitmap mouth = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, r.left+10,r.top+10,r.width()-15,r.height()-15);
        Mat imageMat = new Mat ();
        return mouth;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're using wrong SDK. Follow [this official doc](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) to learn how to use OpenCV for Android.

Comment: agh i have added now the opencv sdk jar file to my project in as my referenced libraries but its still not working